# How do I add functions to LESS in node.js

Tags: node.js, less, extend, middleware, user-defined

I used to use `less-middleware`, but switched to `less` as I needed to add custom functions/constants.  I assume `less-middleware` uses `less` behind the scenes.

To define constants I used:

```
function lessDefine(name, value) {
  less.tree.functions[name] = function () {
    return new (less.tree.Anonymous)(value);
  };
}
```

and to create a constant:

```
lessDefine('backgroundImage', config.backgroundImage);
```

Then to link into Express:

```
router.use('/stylesheets',
  less.middleware(
    lessOpts.source, lessOpts.main,
    lessOpts.parser, lessOpts.compiler));
```

This was after crawling through bug reports, feature requests and google results, as the ability to extend LESS is not well documented.  This worked last week, but now I see:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'middleware'
```

when I try to launch my node app.

What is the "correct" way to add functions/constants to LESS in Node.js?

Note that I use:

```
var less = require('less');
var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware');
```

And my `package.json` uses the following version limits:

```
less-middleware: 1.0.3
less: 1.7.x
```

Comment: I have no idea what `router.use(...)` should do but does `less` object really have this `middleware` method? It all depends on how you've create it I guess (i.e. if you use [`less`](https://github.com/less/less.js) to create `less` object then obviously it has no `middleware` method).

Comment: The code worked a week or so ago but not now.  The `middleware` method was added by `require`ing `less-middleware` I think.  But evidently it is not there now.

Comment: I.e. it looks like what you really need is just to understand how to use `less` instead of `less-middleware` (in context of `Express`). It does not look like it has anything to do with adding functions to the less itself (injecting one into `less.tree.functions` is the correct method I suppose).

Comment: So you have two independent instances of Less compiler in your script: `less` (create with 'less') and `lessMiddleware` (created with 'less-middleware'). Now which one you actually use to compile your less files?

Comment: I assume `less-middleware` uses the `less` module on the backend.  So I'm `require`ing `less` to configure it, but invoking `less-middleware` now (instead of `less.middleware`) to have less called when needed from the middleware stack.  I just ran an `npm dedupe` and ensured that I only have one instance of the `less` module installed, so I'll check again now to see if its working.

Comment: Yes, `less-middleware` may use `less` module behind the scenes but you don't access it by creating *another* object with `var less = require('less');`.

Comment: The dedupe worked, now I'll take a look through the `less-middleware` code to see where it exposes its instance of `less`.

Comment: Interestingly, while searching, I see:
`module.exports = less.middleware = function(source, options, parserOptions, compilerOptions)`...  I guess duplicate instances of the module were the initial problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`less.middleware` is added by the `less-middleware` module.

Monkeypatching is frowned upon for a reason; `less-middleware` had its own `less` module installed within its folder (by npm), while my app was using a separate instance of `less`.

Hence, `less.middleware` was not being set in the instance of `less` that my app sees.  After calling `npm dedupe`, the duplicate instances were consolidated and my app now works.

Comment: Still looks quite weird. A webapp should not depend on where its `npm` modules are installed. In your case accessing the `tree.functions` via another instance of `less` object works only because `tree.functions` itself is a sort of global singleton (that's why it works after `dedupe` and does not w/o it). Ideally you have find the way to get access to the `tree.functions` through the object exposed by the `less-middleware` module (or completely get rid of it and use only `less` module).

Comment: Middleware doesnt expose the underlying less instance, it only monkey patches its instance instead

Comment: Then you simply need to use this "monkey-patched" object to access `tree.functions`. E.g. `var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware'); lessMiddleware.tree.functions[name] = function () { ...`.

Comment: Yes, the original problem was that the monkey-patched object wasn't accessible due to duplicate module instances.